# How i scroll screen in webview page with android calabash

Tags: scroll, webview, calabash-android

I am using default feature to scroll down but that is just scrolled header instead of whole the screen.  I want to screen remaining screen.

Comment: And what have you tried so far to achieve that?

Comment: I tried like search any particular element and execute query , but i did'nt able to  scroll

Answer (score 0):

I) You can use `swipe()`

```
until element_exists("* marked:'selector'") do
    scroll("ScrollView", :down)
 end
```

II) You have to use `evaluate_javascript` for html component,

```
wait_poll(:until_exists => c) do
    evaluate_javascript('webview',"$('selector').scroll();")
end
```